# How to make tabbed mutiple textbox windows

Tags: c#, tabbed-interface

I'm making a text editor and trying to add the tabbed window capability to the textbox.  I've been searching all over heck for info.  Perhaps I'm not asking the question the right way as I keep getting the "accepts tab" posts etc.  Does anyone know code or a post I could use?  If you'd like to see my text editor it's at johnverber.com/dir it's a .exe file just so you're informed.  But I've included a screen shot of my new version:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for tab panels, like the interface of `Notepad++`, or rather to accept tabs inside your `TextBox`?

Comment: screen shot link is not working.

Comment: @MMK Yes it is, I'm viewing it.